# "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key studentId in the item"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm using serverless to expose HTTP request in getwayapi, lambda function and dynamodb but got an error "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key studentId in the item".
Please help me!

Here my code in app.js

```
app.post('/students', function (req, res) {

  const body = req.body;
  const params = {
    TableName: STUDENTS_TABLE,
    Item: {
      "studentId": body.studentId,
      "address": body.address,
      "birth": body.birth,
      "class": body.class,
      "mail": body.mail,
      "name": body.name,
      "phone": body.phone,
      "sex": body.sex,
    }
  }

  dynamoDb.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        success: false,
        message: err
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: true,
        message: 'Created!'
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Please add more details such as your serverless yaml. Looks like the req.body is empty in your lambda invocation, which results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

As user mailtobash said, we are missing a little bit of context to answer your question accurately. Can you add what is inside `req.body` when you send a request to your `POST /students` endpoint?

You can get that value printed in your terminal when you send a request if you use `console.log(req.body)` in the code of your endpoint. If you can't see logs in your development environment, you can have the lambda return `req.body` before executing the rest of your code like so:

```
return res.send({
  success: false,
  requestBody: req.body
})
```

You will then be able to inspect that response in Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) or in your client (if you it's a web-based application, you can go into the dev tools of your browser and look at the details of the request in the Network tab). Knowing what is in `requestBody` will be very helpful.

In any case, the error message indicates that `studentId` is the partition key of `STUDENTS_TABLE` and it is missing. Partition keys are required and must be unique in a DynamoDB table. Additionally, if you are using an existing value, `dynamoDB.put` will overwrite the existing record (but that behavior wouldn't trigger an error).

It seems very likely that the reason why you get that error message from DynamoDB is because `req.body.studentId` is either `undefined`, an empty string (.ie., `""`), or any other value that DynamoDB would consider as "missing" when it comes to set the value of a partition key.

Don't hesitate to take a look at AWS documentation on primary keys: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey